# JWT sign in Post Request returns Incorrect password error

Tags: node.js, jwt, bcrypt

Currently my project takes sign up requests correctly, and stores emails and encrypted passwords into my MongoDB database. However, when I take the same e-mail and password I signed up with, I get an error telling me that my password is incorrect

I have the following sign in request set up:

```
module.exports.login_post = async (req, res) => {
  // shows us the data that was sent.
  // console.log(req.body)
  // destructure to just get the email and password from the body

  const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log('login called')
  try {
    const user = await User.login(email, password);

    // creates and sends a jwt cookie
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });

    res.status(200).json({ user: user._id });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }

  console.log(email, password)
  res.send('user login')
};
```

In this code I reference User.login, which is imported from my User Model

```
userSchema.statics.login = async function (email, password){
  const user = await this.findOne({ email });
  if(user){
    const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if(auth){
      return user
    }
    throw Error('incorrect password')
  }
  throw Error('incorrect email')

}
```

Right now, I can register a user, but when I turn around and use the same login and password in Postman I get the error "incorrect password " from my User.login function.

At this point, I am not sure what steps I should be taking in problem solving this. Is there a way to console.log the encyrpted version of the password I try to log in with, so I can make sure I have Bcrypt set up to correctly encrypt the user's password?

Edit: My signup code was requested:

```
module.exports.signup_post = async (req, res) => {
  // destructure to just get the email and password from the body
  const { eMail, password } = req.body;
  // console.log(email, password)

  // add a try catch block

  try {
    const user = await User.create({
      eMail,
      password,
      words: [

      ]
    });
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
    // (max age is in seconds and this take milliseconds)
    res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    // console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }

  res.send('new signup')
};
```

2nd Edit: and this is my middleware the fires before I save a new user and encrypts the password

```
// hash passwords using SALT
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next){
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()

  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)

  console.log(this.password)
  next()
})
```

Comment: Can you post your signup code?

Comment: Sure, I will add it in the OP

Comment: You need to [hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-hash-a-password) the password when signing up

Comment: Oh, I have some middleware that hashes the password before a user is saved. I juste added my code for that.

Comment: I don't see the middleware code

Comment: I tried adding teh following code to my login function: "console.log('password: ',password,'user.password: ', user.password)" and when I re-ran my code, the login password I used (superSalty8 was trimmed to SuperSalty, now I need to figure out why my password is being trimmed like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code as your password compare you chnage saltRounds with your bcrypt salt rounds it will compare it with password in database

```
const comparePassword = (hashedPassword, password) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword);
}; 

let validations = {
    comparePassword,
}

module.exports = validations;
```